# pandoc error: datafile is missing

Tags: amazon-ec2, centos, pandoc, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am converting html to docx. By using following pandoc command:
pandoc htmlfilename -o docxfilename.
On local system, it works fine. On amazon elastic beanstalk, it throws an error.
Could not find data file /home/ec2-user/.cabal/share/x86_64-linux-ghc-8.4.2/pandoc-
2.2.1/data/abbreviations
return code of pandoc system call is 97.
When I ssh to ec2 instance, file is present there.
pandoc version is 2.2.1

Comment: how did you install pandoc?

Comment: By following these steps:                                                                 
1)wget https://downloads.haskell.org/~platform/8.4.2/haskell-platform-8.4.2-unknown-posix--full-x86_64.tar.gz

2) tar xvf haskell-platform-8.4.2-unknown-posix--full-x86_64

3) sudo ./install-haskell-platform.sh

4) cabal update

5) cabal install pandoc

Comment: probably the user invoking pandoc has not the proper access rights for that directory

Comment: When I used the pandoc dev source code git clone https://github.com/jgm/pandoc
and used stack to install then it works fine. I refer this https://pandoc.org/installing.html

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to install the deb file and not pandoc from Ubuntu:

```
https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/download/3.1.12.1/pandoc-3.1.12.1-1-amd64.deb
```